# Pretty photo() is not a function error in js

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I had Spent a lot of time on searching the solution on it.

I am getting an error that prettyPhoto() is not a function.

from source [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/how-to-make-photo-gallery-using-jquery/)

I had done things:

1. change orders of js.
2. View page source to check wheather js loading or not(its loading).
3. chnaging jquery  min.js versions.
4. try put pretty photo js on same Page inside script tag.
5. try given(on link) Program on another Project.
6. Adding charset utf-8 tag inside script tag.

Links on Page:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Passion+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/thumbnail-gallery.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.MultiFile.js"></script>
    <%--important--%>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <%--important--%>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <%--important--%>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <%--important--%>
    <link href="../css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

my js function  is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
    });
</script>
```

Images Bind on data list.

```
<div id="dvGalleryImages"  align="center">
                <asp:DataList ID="dlGallery" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                    Width="100%">
                    <ItemTemplate> 
                                    <a href='<%# Eval("FilePath")%>' rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" title='<%# Eval("Name") %>'>
                                        <img src='<%# Eval("FilePath")%>' width="100" height="100" alt='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
                                    </a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
            </div>
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery must be included before any JQuery plugins (otherwise when they run they have nothing to plug in to).

*As a side note you are also including 2 different versions JQuery which is useless and will result added download times for your users with zero benefit.*

you want to rewrite your includes to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.MultiFile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are including prettyPhoto before jquery try to include it in last position

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the order of js to this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.MultiFile.js"></script>
<%--important--%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<%--important--%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<%--important--%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
```